# I Don't Want discord.py-rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, requirements.txt

I'm trying to get my Discord bot to run 24/7 on Repl.it and when I installed the source files needed to run the bot it installed the discord.py-rewrite. How do I install the version that's not rewrite? I don't like the rewrite at all & I would have to make loads of changes to my bot & learn a lot of new things.

This is the contents of the requirements.txt file that I used to install the discord.py and a few other things:

```py
discord.py
flask
python-dotenv
```

A code example of the version I want:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say('Hello!')
```

And this is rewrite, which I don't want:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that you want the `0.16.12` version, which was the last release before the `1.0` rewrite release.

```
discord.py==0.16.12
```

You should know, however, that Discord sometimes makes breaking changes to their API (I believe some of these have already happened since `0.16.12` was released).  You won't be able to use new functionality, and you will lose access to some functionality as it is replaced. I really recommend getting used to the rewrite.

Comment: That's actually good to hear, thank you! :-) And it did work.